# For loop not running properly in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, foreach

In this picture, I am trying to get the dashed plots done via a loop (I managed to do so without a loop):

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{arrow marks/.style={postaction=decorate,decoration={markings,
            mark=between positions #1 and 1 step #1 with {\arrow{>}}}},
    arrow marks/.default=10pt}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \begin{adjustwidth}{-0.7in}{-0.7in}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \def\a{0.5}
            \def\lambda{5}

            \begin{axis}[
            axis on top, %so that axes won't get covered up by color
            %xtick distance = {1},
            %ytick distance = {1},
            xmin=-12,xmax=12,
            ymin=-8,ymax=8,
            height = 7in,width=1.2\textwidth,
            axis lines=center,
            axis line style=->, xlabel = {$x_1$}, ylabel={$x_2$},
            %axis equal,
            legend cell align = {left},
            every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=west,},
            every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=south,}, 
            title= {Bang-off-bang Control Trajectories},         title style={xshift=0, yshift=2em},
            domain=-15:15,samples=300,legend pos=outer north east]
            %Final Switch Curve x_2 < 0
            \addplot[->,>=latex,arrow marks=1cm,color = blue, thick, domain = -8:0,tips=proper]({-ln(1-\a*x)/\a^2 - x/\a}, {x}) node[below left, pos = 0.3, font = \small] {\(u^* = 1\)};


            %Final Switch Curve x_2 > 0
            \addplot[->,>=latex,arrow marks=1cm,color = red, thick, domain = 8:0,tips=proper]({ln(1+\a*x)/\a^2 - x/\a}, {x}) node[above right, pos = 0.3, font = \small] {\(u^* = -1\)};

            %Off Curve x_2 > 0
            \addplot[dotted, color = black, thick, domain = 8:0,tips=proper]({ln(1+(\lambda*\a*x)/(\lambda + 2*\a*x))/\a^2 - x/\a}, {x}) node[below left, pos = 0.25, font = \small] {\(u^* = 0\)};

            %Off curve x_2 < 0
            \addplot[dotted, color = black, thick, domain = -8:0,tips=proper]({-ln(1-(\lambda*\a*x)/(\lambda - 2*\a*x))/\a^2 - x/\a}, {x}) node[above right, pos = 0.25, font = \small] {\(u^* = 0\)};

            \foreach \p in {1.5, 1.75, 2, 2.5, 4}
                %Definitions
                \def\xTwoInitPosToZero{\p}
                \def\xOneInitPosToZero{ln(1 +(\lambda*\a* \xTwoInitPosToZero)/(\lambda + 2*\a*\xTwoInitPosToZero))/(\a^2) - \xTwoInitPosToZero/\a}
                \def\zeroControlPosToNeg{ln((2*\a* \xTwoInitPosToZero + \lambda)/\lambda)/\a}
                \def\xTwoInitNegToZero{-\xTwoInitPosToZero}
                \def\xOneInitNegToZero{-ln(1 -(\lambda*\a* \xTwoInitNegToZero)/(\lambda - 2*\a*\xTwoInitNegToZero))/(\a^2) - \xTwoInitNegToZero/\a}
                \def\zeroControlNegToPos{ln((-2*\a* \xTwoInitNegToZero + \lambda)/\lambda)/\a}
                %Pos
                \addplot[->,>=latex,arrow marks=1cm, tips = proper,
                color=red, dashed,thick,domain=-6:0] 
                ({x/\a + (\xTwoInitPosToZero/\a - 1/(\a^2))*(1 - exp(-\a*x)) + \xOneInitPosToZero}, {1/\a + (\xTwoInitPosToZero - 1/\a)*exp(-\a*x)});
                \addplot[->,>=latex, color=red, tips = proper, dashed,thick,domain=0:\zeroControlPosToNeg] ({(\xTwoInitPosToZero/\a)*(1 - exp(-\a*x)) + \xOneInitPosToZero}, {\xTwoInitPosToZero*exp(-\a*x)});
                %Neg
                \addplot[->,>=latex,arrow marks=1cm, tips = proper,
                color=blue, dashed,thick,domain=-6:0] 
                ({-x/\a + (\xTwoInitNegToZero/\a + 1/(\a^2))*(1 - exp(-\a*x)) + \xOneInitNegToZero}, {-1/\a + (\xTwoInitNegToZero + 1/\a)*exp(-\a*x)});
                \addplot[->,>=latex, color=blue, tips = proper, dashed,thick,domain=0:\zeroControlNegToPos] ({(\xTwoInitNegToZero/\a)*(1 - exp(-\a*x)) + \xOneInitNegToZero}, {\xTwoInitNegToZero*exp(-\a*x)});
            }
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{adjustwidth}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

However, I am getting one of the many errors (here's one):
`Undefined control sequence. ...osToZero}, {\xTwoInitPosToZero*exp(-\a*x)});`

I even tried the `\invokepgfplotsforeach` command, but the code just kept on running indefinitely. How can one solve this? (The other queries I have seen have worked for them, but this one isn't working properly).

Comment: There are two issues. First, you forgot an opening brace, `{` after `\foreach \p in {1.5, 1.75, 2, 2.5, 4}`. Second, there is an expansion issue.

Comment: When you say expansion issue, do you mean how the loop traverses over the list?

Comment: No, I mean the issue described on the top of p. 545 of pgfplots manual v1.17.

Comment: Ok, let me check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will be happy to delete this but there is no way I can fit this in a comment. Apart from the obvious missing `{` there is a subtlety with regards to loops in pgfplots. These things are described in the   top part of p. 545 of pgfplots manual v1.17. Basically you need to make sure that the plots get fed with fully expanded macros. I am repeating the recipe there.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{arrow marks/.style={postaction=decorate,decoration={markings,
            mark=between positions #1 and 1 step #1 with {\arrow{>}}}},
    arrow marks/.default=10pt}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \begin{adjustwidth}{-0.7in}{-0.7in}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={a=0.5;lambda=5;}]

            \begin{axis}[
            axis on top, %so that axes won't get covered up by color
            %xtick distance = {1},
            %ytick distance = {1},
            xmin=-12,xmax=12,
            ymin=-8,ymax=8,
            height = 7in,width=1.2\textwidth,
            axis lines=center,
            axis line style=->, xlabel = {$x_1$}, ylabel={$x_2$},
            %axis equal,
            legend cell align = {left},
            every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=west,},
            every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=south,}, 
            title= {Bang-off-bang Control Trajectories},         title style={xshift=0, yshift=2em},
            domain=-15:15,samples=300,legend pos=outer north east]
            %Final Switch Curve x_2 < 0
            \addplot[->,>=latex,arrow marks=1cm,color = blue, thick, domain = -8:0,tips=proper]({-ln(1-a*x)/a^2 - x/a}, {x}) node[below left, pos = 0.3, font = \small] {\(u^* = 1\)};


            %Final Switch Curve x_2 > 0
            \addplot[->,>=latex,arrow marks=1cm,color = red, thick, domain = 8:0,tips=proper]({ln(1+a*x)/a^2 - x/a}, {x}) node[above right, pos = 0.3, font = \small] {\(u^* = -1\)};

            %Off Curve x_2 > 0
            \addplot[dotted, color = black, thick, domain = 8:0,tips=proper]({ln(1+(lambda*a*x)/(lambda + 2*a*x))/a^2 - x/a}, {x}) node[below left, pos = 0.25, font = \small] {\(u^* = 0\)};

            %Off curve x_2 < 0
            \addplot[dotted, color = black, thick, domain = -8:0,tips=proper]({-ln(1-(lambda*a*x)/(lambda - 2*a*x))/a^2 - x/a}, {x}) node[above right, pos = 0.25, font = \small] {\(u^* = 0\)};

            \foreach \p in {1.5, 1.75, 2, 2.5, 4}
                %Definitions
                {\pgfmathsetmacro\xTwoInitPosToZero{\p}
                \pgfmathsetmacro\xOneInitPosToZero{ln(1 +(lambda*a* \xTwoInitPosToZero)/(lambda + 2*a*\xTwoInitPosToZero))/(a^2) - \xTwoInitPosToZero/a}
                \pgfmathsetmacro\zeroControlPosToNeg{ln((2*a* \xTwoInitPosToZero + lambda)/lambda)/a}
                \pgfmathsetmacro\xTwoInitNegToZero{-\xTwoInitPosToZero}
                \pgfmathsetmacro\xOneInitNegToZero{-ln(1 -(lambda*a* \xTwoInitNegToZero)/(lambda - 2*a*\xTwoInitNegToZero))/(a^2) - \xTwoInitNegToZero/a}
                \pgfmathsetmacro\zeroControlNegToPos{ln((-2*a* \xTwoInitNegToZero + lambda)/lambda)/a}
                %Pos
                \edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot[->,>=latex,arrow marks=1cm, tips = proper,
                color=red, dashed,thick,domain=-6:0] 
                ({x/a + (\xTwoInitPosToZero/a - 1/(a^2))*(1 - exp(-a*x)) + \xOneInitPosToZero}, {1/a + (\xTwoInitPosToZero - 1/a)*exp(-a*x)});
                \noexpand\addplot[->,>=latex, color=red, tips = proper, dashed,thick,domain=0:\zeroControlPosToNeg] ({(\xTwoInitPosToZero/a)*(1 - exp(-a*x)) + \xOneInitPosToZero}, {\xTwoInitPosToZero*exp(-a*x)});
                %Neg
                \noexpand\addplot[->,>=latex,arrow marks=1cm, tips = proper,
                color=blue, dashed,thick,domain=-6:0] 
                ({-x/a + (\xTwoInitNegToZero/a + 1/(a^2))*(1 - exp(-a*x)) + \xOneInitNegToZero}, {-1/a + (\xTwoInitNegToZero + 1/a)*exp(-a*x)});
                \noexpand\addplot[->,>=latex, color=blue, tips = proper,
                dashed,thick,domain=0:\zeroControlNegToPos]
                ({(\xTwoInitNegToZero/a)*(1 - exp(-a*x)) +
                \xOneInitNegToZero},
                {\xTwoInitNegToZero*exp(-a*x)});}
                \temp
            }
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{adjustwidth}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There were also two off-topic changes:

1. Several of the `\def`s were replaced by `\pgfmathsetmacro`s. This is somewhat beneficial since the LaTeX does not have to compute these expressions so often when it does the computations in the plots.
2. `\lambda` got replaced by a "function" `lambda`, and likewise for `a`. While it is totally OK to use macros, one may not want to overwrite standard LaTeX commands like `\lambda`. While these changes are just local, you lose the ability to typeset a `\lambda` (without further efforts) and on the long run this practice is almost certainly causing unnecessary headache.

Comment: I know that you have told me in a previous post, but what's beneficial of using `\pgfmathsetmacro{\name}{expression}` or `\pgfmathsetmacro\name{expression}` instead of `\def\name{expression}`?

Comment: @Superman It is only minor but `\pgfmathsetmacro\name{expression}` parses the expression. So when you plot it, LaTeX computes the argument of `\addplot` many times (twice as often as samples, at least). So you prevent it from doing this very often. The gain in performance is not huge, but it might be better practice.

Comment: Even if it's not huge, as small gain can make a difference. Also, I did some research on `\pgfmathsetmacro`, it uses the `\def` command somehow, but under what conditions is `\def` preferred over `\pgfmathsetmacro` (i.e. defining a variable to a set number instead of an expression)?

Comment: @Superman Probably. BTW, w.r.t. good practice: I would not do `\def\lambda{5}`. While this redefinition is only local, it does redefine a macro that typesets the greek letter lambda. If you do that very often, at a give point you will perhaps run into the problem that you can no longer print these greek letters in the plots. So I would hesitate doing this. In general, you can also use `declare function={lambda=5;}` and then just put `lambda` in the expressions without running into the problem of inadvertently redefining a standard macro.

Comment: Ok, might if you put that in your current answer with a comment on it? Just want to make sure that the next time I use it, I don’t make a mistake.

Comment: @Superman Done.

Comment: Oh by the way, instead of `\pgfmathsetmacro\xOneInitPosToZero{ln(1 +(lambda*a* \xTwoInitPosToZero)/(lambda + 2*a*\xTwoInitPosToZero))/(a^2) - \xTwoInitPosToZero/a}`, can one also do `declare function{xTwoInitPosToZero = \p}; declare function{x1InitPosToZero = ln(1 +(lambda*a* xTwoInitPosToZero)/(lambda + 2*a*xTwoInitPosToZero))/(a^2) - xTwoInitPosToZero/a}`? I wonder if this is more "efficient" than using the \pgfmathsetmacros command. I am still learning how to use which over which.

Comment: @Superman This won't parse the expression, just declare it. You can do it, but I am not sure if this brings advantages. What might help to understand the code better is to declare functions for the objects you plot. They look all very similar and can perhaps be broken down to single functions that one may declare.

Comment: Hmmm ok, yeah I think `declare function` may make things more readable when it comes down to plotting objects in `pgfplots`.